# npm ERR! code ENOPACKAGEJSON when using cordova in netbeans

Tags: json, cordova, netbeans, installation

I am trying to get cordova to run with netbeans.  I keep getting error messages,

I created a helloworld html5application provided by netbeans,  I downloaded android studios, node.js, git, and cordova, and set the paths.  when I check the version of git and cordova in the command line everythings good.  please advise.
[Screenshot of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2o41Q.png)

```
check-android-template:
check-cordova-version:
check-cordova-project:
upgrade-to-cordova-project:
create-android:
update-plugins:
cordova.cmd plugins 
cordova.cmd -d plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-dialogs.git
No scripts found for hook "before_plugin_add".
Calling plugman.fetch on plugin "https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-dialogs.git"
fetch: Installing https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-dialogs.git to C:\Users\SONY\Documents\NetBeansProjects\HTML5Application
Running command: npm install https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-dialogs.git --production --save
Failed to fetch plugin https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-dialogs.git via registry.Command finished with error code 1: npm install,https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-dialogs.git,--production,--save
Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.
Error: npm: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
npm ERR! code ENOPACKAGEJSON
npm ERR! package.json Non-registry package missing package.json: https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-dialogs.git.
npm ERR! package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current directory.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\SONY\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-08-10T17_29_09_382Z-debug.log

CordovaError: Failed to fetch plugin https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-dialogs.git via registry.
Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.
Error: npm: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
npm ERR! code ENOPACKAGEJSON
npm ERR! package.json Non-registry package missing package.json: https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-dialogs.git.
npm ERR! package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current directory.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\SONY\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-08-10T17_29_09_382Z-debug.log
    at C:\Users\SONY\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\plugman\fetch.js:146:43
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:5)
C:\Users\SONY\Documents\NetBeansProjects\HTML5Application\nbproject\build.xml:235: exec returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 48 seconds)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. An image of an error message won't register a hit if someone else searched for the text of that error. It is advisable to include the text of any error message in the question and to format it appropriately using either the quote or format as code button.

Comment: That makes sense.  Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're trying to run `npm install` without a **package.json**.

It's impossible to tell what's going on without any way to reproduce the steps.  But you could create a **package.json** by running `npm init` and then run `npm i -S cordova` or `npm i -S cordova-android` if it's an Android application.

Comment: I did `npm init `. it returned :
 `This utility will walk you through creating a package.json file.`
`It only covers the most common items, and tries to guess sensible defaults.`

`See npm help json for definitive documentation on these fields
and exactly what they do.`

`Use npm install <pkg> afterwards to install a package and
save it as a dependency in the package.json file.`

`Press ^C at any time to quit.`
`package name: (sony) `
then  `npm i -S cordova`. it returned 
`Sorry, name can only contain URL-friendly characters and name can no longer contain capital letters.`

Comment: Is there any other information I can provide to help reproduce the steps?